Print lines between two repeated patterns
I have a file like this.
==============
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
id = 1111
some text here
some text here
==============
==============
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
id = 22222
some text here
some text here
==============
==============
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
id = 33333
some text here
some text here
==============

I have to search for the id = 2222 and get the full lines between first and last ======= patterns.
Note: I can't use the exact number of lines after the id = 2222 line as it may vary from file to file.
Program steps:

First find the line with id = 2222.
Go to the first occurrence of ===== line before the id = 2222 line.
Go to the last occurrence of ===== line after the id = 2222 line.
Print all lines between the pattern ===== between id = 2222 line.

Final output will be:
==============
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
id = 22222
some text here
some text here
==============

I was able to do it from below. Updating for your reference.
import collections
import sys
import itertools


# deque to print previous lines once the transuid found.
b = collections.deque(maxlen=3)


# lookup pattern
lookup = '======'

# list for ====== pattern
line_numbers = []



# create a list for ===== lines
with open('test2.txt','r') as f:

# loop through the file
for index,fline in enumerate(f,1):

    if lookup in fline:
       #creating the list with ===== pattern
       line_numbers.append(index)

    if '123' in fline:
        line_numbers.append(index)

f.close()

# Print the main list
# print(line_numbers)


with open('test2.txt','r') as f:
 #lines = f.readlines()
 # print(lines)
 # loop through the file
 for index,fline in enumerate(f,1):
    #print(index, "---", fline)

    if '123' in fline:

        cur_line = int(index)
        cur_index = int(line_numbers.index(cur_line))
        next_index = int(cur_index + 1)
        next_line = line_numbers[next_index]
        prev_index = int(cur_index - 1)
        prev_line = line_numbers[prev_index]


        #print("prev_index = ", prev_index)
        #print("cur index = ", cur_index)
        #print("next index = ", next_index)


        #print("prev_line=", prev_line)
        #print("cur line = ", cur_line)
        #print("next_line=", next_line)

        print("********* Start Flow *************")
        specified_lines = []
        for x in range(prev_line, next_line+1):
            specified_lines.append(x)
        #print(specified_lines)

        f2 = open("test2.txt")
        for pos, l_num in enumerate(f2,1):
            # check if the line number is specified in the lines 
to read array
            if pos in specified_lines:
                # print the required line number
                print(l_num)
        print("********* End Flow *************")

    b.append(fline)



f.close()


Note that it would be useful if you'd posted the actual output as well as the desired output.

s = file.read()  for m in re.finditer(r'==============.+?==============',s,flags=re.S):

If the problem is missing delimiters in the output, add newfile.write(START_PATTERN) and newfile.write(END_PATTERN) in the corresponding if statements.

P.S. Include actual output in your question.
